# Remove Text from the edit text when edit text is focused

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I want to remove the text when the edit text is focused programmatically, when i try to do that the fragment class throws null pointer exception.

The design which i am using is Material Text Input Layout, when i set the hint in the text input layout, the hint goes upward in the box which is around the TextInputLayout and i don't want that. i just want the box,

So i set the text as an hint in the EditTextField in the XML file and i want to remove the text when user click in the EditText or when the EditText is focused.

Here is the Screen Recorded for better understanding of the issue

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EgBymObb4A

Here is the layout XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".screens.fragments.login_fragment"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semi_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txt_login_des"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_des"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your Credintials to get access"
        android:textColor="#9CFFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_id_feild"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#FF0000"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_login_des"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/password_feild">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/LoginUserIDField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"
            android:text="User ID"
            android:textColor="#74FFFFFF"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_user_edit_txt_input"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_feild"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#FF0000"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_signIn">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/UserLoginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="•••••••••••••"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_pass_txt_input"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#74FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_signIn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:rippleColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_register"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:rippleColor="@color/black"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_fab_btns_lyt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fab_btns_lyt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

         <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
             android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
             style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             app:strokeWidth="1dp"
             app:strokeColor="@color/white"
             app:icon="@drawable/icons8_facebook"
             app:iconTintMode="add"
             app:iconSize="24dp"
             app:iconTint="#000000"
             app:iconPadding="0dp"
             android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
             android:backgroundTintMode="add"
             app:backgroundTintMode="add"
             app:rippleColor="@color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_google"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:icon="@drawable/google_cute_icon"
        app:iconTintMode="add"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="#000000"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        app:backgroundTintMode="add"
        app:rippleColor="@color/white"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:icon="@drawable/google_cute_icon"
        app:iconTintMode="add"
        app:iconSize="24dp"
        app:iconTint="#000000"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        app:backgroundTintMode="add"
        app:rippleColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Class

```
package com.ak_applications.kottry.screens.fragments

import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.ak_applications.kottry.R
import com.ak_applications.kottry.databinding.FragmentLoginFragmentBinding

class login_fragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login_fragment) {


    private var _binding: FragmentLoginFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       _binding = FragmentLoginFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }




        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            _binding = null
        }
}
```

I tried

```
if(binding.LoginUserFeild.isFocused)
{
 binding.LoginUserFeild.setText("")
 binding.LoginUserFeild.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
}
```

also

```
if(binding.LoginUserFeild.isFocused)
{
 binding.userLoginfeild.setHint("") // which is TextInputLayout.
}
```

also I have used the scroll layout as parent layout for the fragment but as you can see in the screen recording when user click on the EditText Feild the layout goes to top but user scroll down while the EditText selected the layout won't go all the way to up, layout missing somthing i don't know.

I am new to android please help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
binding.LoginUserFeild.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
      binding.LoginUserFeild.setText("")      
    }
}
```

Comment: bro in which method should i use this i mean inside the OnCreate(), onCreateView(), onCViewCreated(), etc @Александр Волошиновский

Comment: use in onViewCreated - here the view is ready for use

Comment: I'll just try and let you know

Comment: hey bro can you tell me something about layout if have seen the video, i have attached link for that video above in my question

Comment: it's nice layout

Comment: no bro i am not asking how is the layout , i am asking for solution for layout the layout do not scroll all the way up to the top when user click on any edit text or the android soft key board appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233161/discussion-between-akki-jangir-and--).